# How to get geometry normals in cycles like in blender internal?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, shaders, normals

I need view dependent normal output in cycles, is it possible to convert things somehow?

[image]

Comment: You mean the camera texture coordinate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9lGm.png?

Comment: No, it's different thing https://gyazo.com/e2c6d922931432b5ca6c7351a0e1c924

Comment: I see, I'll leave it to someone who knows more about the theory behind the topic.

Comment: I was going to give this answer but someone else already has: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69317/cycle-normal-pass-in-camera-space

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks! exactly what i needed