# How to retrieve correct normal information of a render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals, render-layers, denoise

How can I get the the same vector for every angle on denoising normal information when rendering in Cycles? 
I realized that, based on the camera angle and its position, the normal vector is different. Sometimes it is green (RGB)::(0,1,0) and sometimes black (0,-1,0).
I checked the normals on all objects, so they are correct. When I show my normals they go in both directions.

[image: Denoising Normal Layer]]  [image: different angle - Denoising Normal Layer]

What I want is that even when my camera is in another position, the vector should be not (0,-1,0) but instead be green. 
For example: in the first image the cupboards should be greenish and not black.

Comment: I myself don't know how to answer this question, but it may be helpful for those than could if you included why you want to be able to do this.

Comment: I want my normal information to be in camera space not in world space, so all my normal information are having the same structure of information. 
I need them as training data for a neural network. 
But it seems like I should have searched for my problems differently.
These posts seem to answer my needs: 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69317/cycle-normal-pass-in-camera-space
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157271/render-normals-in-camera-space

Comment: I also just found out, that with Blender 2.82 this behaviour of Cycles has changed. 
Now the 'Denoising Normal' layer does output its values in camera space instead of world space.
See: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.82/Cycles

Comment: Always get the latest version :)